# How do I make children elements stay within the parent element when view height/width is changed?

Tags: css

Here is a codepen. Pay attention to the purple elements when you change the view height. They overflow. I want to slay this dragon once and for all - and more importantly - understand what is happening so I never have to bother you folks again.

https://codepen.io/colbisaurusrex/pen/WpXVxY

```
 body {
  background-color: #34495E;
  padding: 5%;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.columnleft {
  background-color: #2ECC71;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.leftbox {
  margin: 10%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #1ABC9C;
  margin: 10%;
  height: 40%;
}

.innerbox {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  height: 96%;
  width: 47%;
  margin: 2%;
}


.columnright {
  background-color: #2ECC71; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #9B59B6;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.rowone {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.rowtwo {
 margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so as I see in your code, you are using flex buuut... not really.

I corrected your `columnright` but you can do the same with `columnleft` if you understood.

What you want to achieve is having elements inside column with the same "height" and take the full space.

So here is the corrected CSS :

```
.columnright {
  background-color: #2ECC71;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #9B59B6;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.rowtwo {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Remove everything from rowone.

What I used is the `flex` property that define how much space an element will take. Here, each element will have to take 1 unit of space, so each one the same amount of height. I also added a margin-top to each element to create an "internal" padding and a margin-bottom to the last element.

Also, here is the corrected CodePen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxpBjM

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so let's take an example. You have an element called `columnright`. Inside it you have `rowone` and `rowtwo`.

The `rowone` have a rendered height and margin as:

```
height: 40%;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-bottom: 5%;
```

The `rowtwo` have a rendered height and margin as:

```
height: 40%;
margin-bottom: 5%;
```

So `40% + 5% + 5% + 40% + 5% = 95%`, right? It shouldn't overflow right? **Not actually**

***The problem:***

As stated in [CSS box model spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties):

> The [margin] percentage is calculated **with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block**. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

So, when you set margin top/bottom it is relative to the width, not to the height. If your element is rectangle *(as is yours in the example)*, it will overflow at some point, for the `width` is higher than the `height`.

***What you can do about it:***

Well, it would be best not to use percentage margin if the parent element has a defined height. Other than that, you could remove the `height` from the parent if it suits your needs

Comment: I never knew percentage's were calculated based on parent width and not height. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good questions are always welcome. This is, after all, a site where we volunteer our time to help others, so it's anything but bothersome as long as a meaningful exchange of knowledge takes place.

Add the `overflow: hidden`, `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll` property to the containing `<div>`s' styles, depending on which effect you wish to achieve. See [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp) for more information on the `overflow:` property.

The `overflow:` property also comes in two sub-flavours, specifically `overflow-x:` and `overflow-y:`, each of which can have individual values if you so choose.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was aware of the overflow property, but I wanted to elements to be responsive and change in size. Should have been more clear.